# Assembly add syntax with hex preceding the register

Tags: assembly, x86, hex, addition, att

```
add  -0x4(%rbx), %eax
```

My question is how to interpret the above statement. My guess is that you get the address stored in rbx, and subtract 4 from that address, then find the value IN the resulting address, and then you add that value to the value stored in eax. Is this correct?

Comment: The only addition I would make is that the value being referenced at the memory address is considered to be a LONG(dword) since the destination operand %EAX is 32-bits. It could have been written as `addl  -0x4(%rbx), %eax` but GNU assembler can infer the target size in this case.